# Border image with opacity

Tags: css, opacity, border-image

I have this:

```
.striped-border {
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(../img/stripes.png) 9 round;
}
```

[image: Content with a border-image]

What I want:

[image]

Is it possible to apply an opacity to the **border-image only** and not the content?

Comment: Add the border-image to a pseudo-element and use opacity

Comment: @Nenad's solution: https://jsfiddle.net/bu6xt7pc/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `pseudo-element` to create border with `border-image` and then set `opacity`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-image: url('http://www.circlek.org/Libraries/2013_branding_design_elements/graphic_CKI_horizontal_stripesblue_RGB.sflb.ashx') 22 22 repeat;
  transform: translate(-5px, -5px);
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div>Element</div>
<div>Element <br> lorem</div>
```

Comment: Follow-up question: When adding a form, with an input and button, they show but apparently disabled. Any idea to enable them? Thanks again! https://jsfiddle.net/bu6xt7pc/3/

Answer (score 2):

What about something like it:

```
.striped-border:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
    border:8px solid rgba(256,256,256, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: rgba won't work. OP needs border-image and not just solid color. That being said... Pseudo-elements are the way to go.

Comment: Jacques Marais, try setting top, left, bottom, right to 8px. make sure that .striped-border:after is at the from of your element

Comment: @Mohsen tried setting to 8px but no luck https://jsfiddle.net/xd1s93hb/3/

Comment: oh dear Carlos, set them to 8px not 8