# Is is possible to add grain to box-shadow?

Tags: html, css, sass

A client wants the grain effect on the box-shadow of this modal.

You can see the grain the box-shadow in the screenshot attached.

How can I achive this using CSS? I've looked but couldn't find anything.[image][image]

Tried adding an after with a grain effect and applying the box-shadow to it

```
.grain {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background: transparent url(grain.jpg) 0 0;
    background-size: 320px 320px;
    opacity: .1!important;
    z-index: 30;
    background-color: #000;
    pointer-events: none;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Comment: You can use border-image to use your grainy image and set the opacity as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085415/border-image-with-opacity

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `.png` image with transparency; I found a bunch [here](https://www.transparenttextures.com/).
Set `position: relative` on your element, and `position: absolute` on the `::after` pseudo-element.

```css
.grainy-shadow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.grainy-shadow::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  bottom: -1rem;
  right: -1rem;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/black-orchid.png");
}

body {
  background: url(https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/colorful-random-shapes-abstract-background-geometrical-circle-background-with-copy-space-yellow_655111-46.jpg?w=2000);
}
```

```html
<div class="grainy-shadow">
  <h1>content</h1>
</div>
```